# Spark + Intellij + Azure - output to screen

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, intellij-idea, azure-hdinsight

I'm using Intellij to write Scala code which is then sent to an Azure HDInsight spark cluster for execution.  I'm getting log details about the job being run but I'm not seeing any output from my `println()` statements.

Is this normal?  Is there some way to see output from the program execution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal. Why don't you try our new remote debug feature to connect to HDInsight cluster and step through your code. Please find the documentation and debug video below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-intellij-tool-debug-remotely-through-ssh

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQtj_wjn1Ac

Let us know should you have any more questions.

Thanks,
-Jenny

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, please refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-tools-for-java/issues/957